# Query on table joined with itself

Tags: sql, join, self-join, ansi-sql

Today I have a final Exam. I approved, happily :D but one of the problems is really blowing my mind.

I need help, so I can rest in peace.

**THE PROBLEM**

We have a table "People"

```
(PK)id | name | fatherID
    ---------------------
    1  | gon  |   2
    2  | cesar|   6
    3  | luz  |   2
    4  | maria|   5
    5  | diego|   6
    6  | john |  -
```

this is only an example of data.
This table has a relation with itself, on table fatherId(FK) with table id(PK)
I need to do a query that show me 2 columns, in one the name of a person, and in the another one, his/her cousin.

Pretty simple until here, right?
The problem is that I have some restrictions

- ONLY ANSI allowed. NO T-sql, or another one. Also, ANSI 99 standard, not 2003 or higher
- subquerys are not allowed. And the worst:
- NO relations repeated.

For example, considering in this example, gon and maria are cousins.
If I show, `gon | maria` in the results, I can't show `maria | gon`.

SO, how I can do this?
Is really burning my head.

**What I tried?**

Well, the big problem was in the last requisite, the repetition of data. Ignoring that, I put this on my exam (knowing is wrong..)

```
select p3.name as OnePerson, p4.name as Cousin
from
people p1
inner join people p2 on p1.fatherid = p2.fatherid and p1.id != p2.id
inner join people p3 on p1.id = p3.fatherid
inner join people p4 on p1.id = p4.fatherid
```

of course, this is not solving the last requeriment, and I have a 4 in the test(we pass with 4) but anyway, my head is burning. So please, help me!

**Another options explored**

one of my friends, that also had the same exam said me

> "Well, considering every relation is duplicated, I can use top
>   count(*) and an order by and get the half correct"

but.. `Top` is not `ANSI`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to your query `WHERE p3.id < p4.id`. This will eliminate duplicate results like `gon | maria` and `maria | gon`.

Answer (score 0):

***This will give you the results in format you want.***

```
SELECT TAB1.ID,TAB2.ID
FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM people T1
 WHERE fatherID IN ( SEL T1.ID FROM people T1 INNER JOIN  people T2 
ON(     T1.id=T2.fatherID) WHERE T1.fatherID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 1) ) TAB1

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM people T1
WHERE fatherID IN ( SEL T1.ID FROM people T1 INNER JOIN  people T2 
ON(   T1.id=T2.fatherID)WHERE T1.fatherID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 1) ) TAB2

ON( TAB1.fatherID<>TAB2.fatherID)
GROUP BY 1,2
WHERE TAB1.ID <TAB2.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.id , T2.id FROM 
(
    SELECT A.id,A.fid FROM family A 
    WHERE a.fid IN 
    ( 
        SELECT id FROM family
        WHERE fid IN (SELECT id FROM family WHERE fid IS NULL)
    )
)T1

JOIN
(
     SELECT A.id,A.fid FROM family A 
     WHERE a.fid IN 
     ( 
          SELECT id FROM family
          WHERE fid IN (SELECT id FROM family WHERE fid IS NULL)
     )
)T2
ON t1.fid<>t2.fid
AND t1.id<t2.id
```